# Magento order not redirect to payment gateway in one page checkout

Tags: php, magento, redirect

We are currently using third party one page checkout.Problem is when we place order using 2checkout payment method it not redirect to gateway site it just redirected to me "www.mydomain.com/tco/redirect/". 
I think

```
public function indexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('tco/redirect');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->renderLayout();

}
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {

    return Mage::getUrl('tco/redirect');

}
```

indexAction method not working properly. But when we deactivate third party one page checkout and activate magento default opc its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You just try with the following function

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {

   $this->_redirect('tco/redirect');

}
```

Comment: No its not working for me. It is directly redirected me to magento success page.

Comment: Can u post your config.xml?

Comment: Okay please check my config.xml below, Actually i am trying 2checkout payment gateway with IWD one page checkout extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
<modules>

    <Craig_Tco>

        <version>2.4.2</version>

    </Craig_Tco>

</modules>

<global>

    <models>

        <tco>

            <class>Craig_Tco_Model</class>

        </tco>

    </models>

    <helpers>

        <tco>

            <class>Craig_Tco_Helper</class>

        </tco>

    </helpers>

    <blocks>

        <tco>

            <class>Craig_Tco_Block</class>

        </tco>

    </blocks>

    <resources>

        <tco_setup>

            <setup>

                <module>Craig_Tco</module>

            </setup>

            <connection>

                <use>directory_setup</use>

            </connection>

        </tco_setup>

        <tco_write>

            <connection>

                <use>local_write</use>

            </connection>

        </tco_write>

        <tco_read>

            <connection>

                <use>local_read</use>

            </connection>

        </tco_read>

    </resources>

  <events>

    <controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>

      <observers>

        <output_tco_redirect>

          <type>singleton</type>

          <class>Craig_Tco_Model_Observer</class>

          <method>output_tco_redirect</method>

        </output_tco_redirect>

      </observers>

    </controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>

    <sales_order_creditmemo_refund>

      <observers>

        <issue_creditmemo_refund>

          <type>singleton</type>

          <class>Craig_Tco_Model_Observer</class>

          <method>issue_creditmemo_refund</method>

        </issue_creditmemo_refund>

      </observers>

    </sales_order_creditmemo_refund>

  </events>

</global>

<frontend>

    <layout>

        <updates>

            <tco>

                <file>tco.xml</file>

            </tco>

        </updates>

    </layout>

    <routers>

        <tco>

            <use>standard</use>

            <args>

                <module>Craig_Tco</module>

                <frontName>tco</frontName>

            </args>

        </tco>

    </routers>

    <secure_url>

        <tco_redirect>/tco/redirect/</tco_redirect>

    </secure_url>

</frontend>

<default>

    <payment>

        <tco>

            <active>1</active>

            <submit_url>1</submit_url>

            <model>tco/checkout</model>

            <title>2Checkout (Visa, MasterCard, Amex, Discover, JCB, Diners Club, Debit Card, PayPal)</title>

            <sid>Enter 2Checkout Account Number</sid>

            <secret_word>Enter your Secret Word</secret_word>

            <submit_url>1</submit_url>

            <demo>0</demo>

            <sort_order>1</sort_order>

        </tco>

    </payment>

</default>
```